# Title element won't display after adding javascript, but works when I remove it

Tags: javascript, html, title

So I know this is a super noob question but after adding a script tag for a .js file,my title element stops working.

As an example :

```
<html>
<title>TEST</title>
<head> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="datetime.js"></script>
</head> 
 <body onload="showDateTime()"> 
    <p> 
    </p>
  </body>
  </script>
</html>
```

yet if I delete the `"<script type="text/javascript" src="datetime.js"></script>"` portion, the title element works again. ANy help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- The title tag must be placed inside the `<head></head>`
- The `<script>` tag is incorrectly nested. It must be closed in the head

  ```
  <html>
    <head> 
      <title>TEST</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="datetime.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body onload="showDateTime()"> 
      <p id='datetime-container'> 
     </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

The code above should work.

Comment: Copied and pasted this, and still experiencing same result.. :S.. The script loads correctly, but the title is the filename of the html doc, not the "title" (TEST)

Comment: Can you also post datetime.js?

Comment: yup, it is : 
function showDateTime () { var now = new Date (); document.write ("It is now " + now); }

Comment: Your datetime.js file and the fixed HTML above worked for me. I see: "It is now Mon Sep 01 2014 18:13:11 GMT-0400 (EDT)"

Comment: Yeah the .js file works fine, but the title of the webpage <title>TEST</title> does not work at the same time as the .js does. When I remove the .js, the correct webpage title works, but if the .js  is added, the title of the webpage displays as "index.html" as opposed to "TEST"

Comment: Ah, `document.write(...)` replaces the whole page. Use the html above and replace `document.write(...)` with `document.getElementById('datetime-container').innerHTML = now;`

Answer (score 0):

The title tag needs to be inside the head.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp